# Difficulties with Gnuradio on Odroid C1

Tags: python, ubuntu, gnuradio, odroid

I really hope that you can help me. So I wrote a simple Programm in Gnu Radio Companion that is able to transmit a text file with use of a HackRf One. The Programm works fine on my two laptops (both on Ubuntu 15.10, latest GNU-Radio and Osmocom), but when I try to launch it on my Odroid C1, the Programm seems to work normally, but there is no data transfer. The HackRF is powered by a USB-HUB, so that can't be the problem. Do you have any ideas?

Transmitter(not the problem):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
##################################################
# GNU Radio Python Flow Graph
# Title: Top Block
# Generated: Tue Feb 23 19:31:30 2016
##################################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import ctypes
    import sys
    if sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
        try:
            x11 = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('libX11.so')
            x11.XInitThreads()
        except:
            print "Warning: failed to XInitThreads()"

from gnuradio import analog
from gnuradio import blocks
from gnuradio import eng_notation
from gnuradio import filter
from gnuradio import gr
from gnuradio import wxgui
from gnuradio.eng_option import eng_option
from gnuradio.fft import window
from gnuradio.filter import firdes
from gnuradio.wxgui import fftsink2
from grc_gnuradio import wxgui as grc_wxgui
from optparse import OptionParser
import wx


class top_block(grc_wxgui.top_block_gui):

    def __init__(self):
        grc_wxgui.top_block_gui.__init__(self, title="Top Block")

        ##################################################
        # Variables
        ##################################################
        self.samp_rate = samp_rate = 32000

        ##################################################
        # Blocks
        ##################################################
        self.wxgui_fftsink2_0 = fftsink2.fft_sink_f(
            self.GetWin(),
            baseband_freq=0,
            y_per_div=10,
            y_divs=10,
            ref_level=0,
            ref_scale=2.0,
            sample_rate=samp_rate,
            fft_size=1024,
            fft_rate=15,
            average=False,
            avg_alpha=None,
            title="FFT Plot",
            peak_hold=False,
        )
        self.Add(self.wxgui_fftsink2_0.win)
        self.rational_resampler_xxx_0 = filter.rational_resampler_fff(
                interpolation=2000000,
                decimation=44100,
                taps=None,
                fractional_bw=None,
        )
        self.blocks_multiply_xx_0 = blocks.multiply_vff(1)
        self.blocks_file_source_0 = blocks.file_source(gr.sizeof_float*1, "test.txt", True)
        self.analog_const_source_x_0 = analog.sig_source_f(0, analog.GR_CONST_WAVE, 0, 0, 1)

        ##################################################
        # Connections
        ##################################################
        self.connect((self.analog_const_source_x_0, 0), (self.blocks_multiply_xx_0, 1))    
        self.connect((self.blocks_file_source_0, 0), (self.blocks_multiply_xx_0, 0))    
        self.connect((self.blocks_multiply_xx_0, 0), (self.rational_resampler_xxx_0, 0))    
        self.connect((self.rational_resampler_xxx_0, 0), (self.wxgui_fftsink2_0, 0))    

    def get_samp_rate(self):
        return self.samp_rate

    def set_samp_rate(self, samp_rate):
        self.samp_rate = samp_rate
        self.wxgui_fftsink2_0.set_sample_rate(self.samp_rate)


def main(top_block_cls=top_block, options=None):

    tb = top_block_cls()
    tb.Start(True)
    tb.Wait()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the Receiver (does not work on Odroid):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
##################################################
# GNU Radio Python Flow Graph
# Title: Top Block
# Generated: Tue Jan  5 20:44:14 2016
##################################################

from gnuradio import blocks
from gnuradio import digital
from gnuradio import eng_notation
from gnuradio import gr
from gnuradio.eng_option import eng_option
from gnuradio.filter import firdes
from grc_gnuradio import blks2 as grc_blks2
from optparse import OptionParser
import osmosdr
import time


class top_block(gr.top_block):

    def __init__(self):
        gr.top_block.__init__(self, "Top Block")

        ##################################################
        # Variables
        ##################################################
        self.samp_rate = samp_rate = 32000

        ##################################################
        # Blocks
        ##################################################
        self.osmosdr_source_0 = osmosdr.source( args="numchan=" + str(1) + " " + "" )
        self.osmosdr_source_0.set_sample_rate(2e6)
        self.osmosdr_source_0.set_center_freq(2400e6, 0)
        self.osmosdr_source_0.set_freq_corr(0, 0)
        self.osmosdr_source_0.set_dc_offset_mode(0, 0)
        self.osmosdr_source_0.set_iq_balance_mode(0, 0)
        self.osmosdr_source_0.set_gain_mode(False, 0)
        self.osmosdr_source_0.set_gain(0, 0)
        self.osmosdr_source_0.set_if_gain(20, 0)
        self.osmosdr_source_0.set_bb_gain(20, 0)
        self.osmosdr_source_0.set_antenna("", 0)
        self.osmosdr_source_0.set_bandwidth(1000, 0)

        self.digital_gmsk_demod_0 = digital.gmsk_demod(
            samples_per_symbol=2,
            gain_mu=0.175,
            mu=0.5,
            omega_relative_limit=0.005,
            freq_error=0.0,
            verbose=False,
            log=False,
        )
        self.blocks_multiply_const_vxx_0 = blocks.multiply_const_vcc((1, ))
        self.blocks_file_sink_0 = blocks.file_sink(gr.sizeof_float*1, "test", False)
        self.blocks_file_sink_0.set_unbuffered(False)
        self.blks2_packet_decoder_0 = grc_blks2.packet_demod_f(grc_blks2.packet_decoder(
                access_code="",
                threshold=0,
                callback=lambda ok, payload: self.blks2_packet_decoder_0.recv_pkt(ok, payload),
            ),
        )

        ##################################################
        # Connections
        ##################################################
        self.connect((self.blks2_packet_decoder_0, 0), (self.blocks_file_sink_0, 0))    
        self.connect((self.blocks_multiply_const_vxx_0, 0), (self.digital_gmsk_demod_0, 0))    
        self.connect((self.digital_gmsk_demod_0, 0), (self.blks2_packet_decoder_0, 0))    
        self.connect((self.osmosdr_source_0, 0), (self.blocks_multiply_const_vxx_0, 0))    

    def get_samp_rate(self):
        return self.samp_rate

    def set_samp_rate(self, samp_rate):
        self.samp_rate = samp_rate


def main(top_block_cls=top_block, options=None):

    tb = top_block_cls()
    tb.start()
    try:
        raw_input('Press Enter to quit: ')
    except EOFError:
        pass
    tb.stop()
    tb.wait()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks a Lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend connecting the Hackrf directly to a USB port on the C1 - hubs can mess up timing.

Looking at the transmitter code, I don't see a osmosdr sink - or any sink that transmits.

It looks like you're simply mixing text with a cosine and looking at in a FFT sink.